# jQuery UI Tabs: show another div with each active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery Tabs UI with standard the tabs structure ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ ). I haven't included all the html here, as it's redundant if you're familiar with Tabs UI.

But in this case, what I need to do is show a different image for each active tab. I.e. a different image in #headerwrapper when #tabone is active and another when #tabtwo is active, etc. And ideally fade in/out those images with something like the fx opacity effect.

My tabs init looks like this:

```
var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs({
    });
```

It looks like I need to do this (according to Matt's answer, below) in order to find the active tab:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
select: function(event, ui) { .... });
```

But I've had no luck with Matt's answer.

This is the headerwrapper and image CSS:

```
#headerwrapper {
background: url(images/image.jpg) top center no-repeat;
height:88px;
}
```

Is it possible to show a different image for each tab and fx them (i.e., fx: {opacity: 'toggle'} )  as they change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `data-*` attributes:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function($event, ui) {
        /* Extract the image from the active tab: */
        var img = $(ui.panel).data("image");

        /* Animate the header out, set the background css, then animate back in: */
        $("#headerwrapper")
            .animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, function() {
                $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + img + ")")
                    .animate({ opacity: 'toggle' });
            });
    }
});
```

And each tab panel would have `data-image` defined:

```
<div id="tabs-1" data-image="http://placekitten.com/g/300/88">...</div>
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8muBm/2/

Comment: This is close to what I'm trying to do, but how can I swap the background image in CSS?

Comment: @songdogtech: I will take another look at the question and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @songdogtech: See my updated answer--Please let me know if it doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanks! This works great. There's a nice transition between images. Only problem I have now is when I load the Tabs page for the first time (or reload the page, which no one will be doing in normal use), no image shows, so I don't know how to fix that. Somehow set a default image?

Comment: @songdogtech: If you load the page for the first time, the default `background-image` for `#headerwrapper` should show (at least in the example). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I should have realized that. Works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the image itself. So depending on what tab you are on, you could rename the images as header0, header1, etc... You can use

```
$('#example').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var selected = $('#example').tabs('option', 'selected');
        $("#headerimg").attr("src", "/new/image/header" + selected + ".jpg");
    }
});
```

Something like that should work. You can get the currently selected tab. Otherwise you can always use an if/else statement as well.

Comment: Much better idea than what I was thinking of; I can use headerimg1, etc., for the image names. How would I work with the CSS (added above) and the attr in the function to take into account it is a background image?

Comment: @songdogtech I honestly never worked with jquery and css before, but http://api.jquery.com/css/ you can manipulate it.